# h2o aggregate method "none" mapping unknown words to NAN and not vector

Tags: python, word2vec, h2o

I am currently using h2o.ai to perform some NLP. I have a trained model for my corpus in Word2Vec and have successfully aggregated a number of records with the method "Average". The problem comes in when I want to create features for my DRF model by using this w2v model to create a bag of words for each entry. When I use the aggregate method "none" the vectors are returned in a single column containing NaN's where The records begin and end, however the unknown words in the model are also being mapped to NaN and not the the unknown word vector. This is stopping me from reorganizing the vectors into a bag of words for each record because the record separation association is lost due to the extra and unpredictably entered NaNs. Is there a fix for this?

I am currently going to use the original tokenized list to make an index of the original double NaN structure that is used to deliminate between records and then recombine my vectors based off of this. Just wanted to throw this out there to see if anyone else is dealing with this or if there is some type of fix in place that I cannot find on the interwebs.

```
DATA = pd.read_sql(sql, conn1)

steps = [
    (r'[\n\t\’\–\”\“\!~`\"@#\$%\^\&\*()_+\{\}|:<>\?\-=\[\]\\;\',./\d]', ' '), 

    (r'\s+', ' ')
    ]

steps = [ (re.compile(a), b) for (a, b) in steps ] 

def do_steps(anarr):
    for pattern,replacement in steps:
        anarr = pattern.sub(replacement,anarr)
    return anarr

DATA.NARR = DATA.NARR.apply(do_steps)

train_hdata = h2o.H2OFrame(DATA).ascharacter()
train_narr = train_hdata["NARR"]
train_key = train_hdata["KEY"]
train_tokens_narr = train_narr.tokenize(split=' ')

train_vecs = w2v.transform(train_tokens_narr, aggregate_method='NONE')
VECS = train_vecs.as_data_frame()
df = train_tokens_narr.as_data_frame()
B=(VECS.isnull()&df.isnull())
idx = B[B['C1'] == True].index.tolist()
X = []
X.append('')
j=0
for i in tqdm(range(len(VECS.C1)-1)):
    if i in idx:
        X[j]= X[j][:-2]
        j+=1
        X.append('')
    else:
        X[j]= X[j] + str(VECS.C1[i])[:6] + ', '

s = pd.DataFrame({"C1":X})
print(s)
```

The above is the current code looking to take some records and encode them with the word2vec model for a bag of words. The bottom portion is a draft loop that I am using to put the correct vectors with the correct records. Let me know if I need to clarify.

Comment: Consider reading this article and editing your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: can you post a code snippet with an end-to-end example so we can see what language you are using and reproduce the issue you are having, please also include what version of h2o-3 you are using.

Comment: I made changes and posted a sample of my code. I am using Python and h2o v3.18.0.11

Comment: Changed my code a bit so that it is updated to the current working version. But its majorly slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the functionality to distinguish between words that are missing from your dictionary and NAs used to demarcate the start and end of a record is not currently available. I've made a jira ticket [here](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5867) to track the issue. Please feel free to comment or update the ticket.

Comment: Thanks! This is sort of what I was looking for.